# How to add package in virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

I created virtual environment with

```
conda create -n vtenv pandas numpy jupyter matplotlib
source activate vtenv
```

But I want to load another package, say tensorflow, which is installed on my machine but not in the virtual environment. How do I add it to the environment? Thanks very much!

Comment: You have to install that package into the virtual environment. You may do it either using `pip install tensorflow`or `conda install tensorflow` if you want to include the version of the package the use `tensoflow==1.2`

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of the packages installed in the default python inside the conda environment. All we need to do is, set the path of python bin in the PATH variable.

However if you want a different version of a package, say tensorflow, it is better to install it inside the environment using conda install. This will help to avoid the conflict between the package versions.